# echo in the form instead in the config file if login failed

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a login div/page. At this time, the login form has an action of external file which is config.php. Whenever user click submit, of course it will go to config.php file, and if user fails to login, in the config.php file the user will redirect back to login.html page.

My question now is how to echo it in the bellow/at the bottom of the form if the user fails to login?

This is my codes:

```
   <?php
   session_start();

   // include connection file
   include("configPDO.php");

  $member_email=$_POST['member_email']; 
  $member_password=$_POST['member_password']; 
  $return = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['return']);

  $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE member_email = :member_email AND member_password = :member_password");

 $STM->bindParam(':member_email', $member_email);
 $STM->bindParam(':member_password', $member_password);

 $STM->execute();

 $count = $STM->rowCount();

 $row  = $STM -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 if ( $count == 1 )  {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['member_id'];
     $_SESSION['member_name'] = $row['member_name']; // added
     $_SESSION['member_email'] = $row['member_email']; // added
            //echo 'SESSION =' .$_SESSION['myusername'];              
            //echo 'ROW =' .$row['myusername'];
            //var_dump($row);
    if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] != '' || $_SESSION['login_id'] > 0 ) { // edited
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   
    } else { 
        header("location: .$return");  
    }
}



 else 
 {
 header("location:.$return");
 }
 $dbh = null;
 ?>
```

This is my form:

```
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="config-login.php">
            <table width="345" align="center" style="background:honeydew; vertical-align:top; margin:0px auto; border:solid medium yellowgreen;">
                <td class="myimage">Email :</td>
                <td width="196" style="padding-right:2px;"><input type="text" name="member_email" style="width:100%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="myimage">Password : </td>
                <td style="padding-right:2px;"><input type="password" name="member_password" style="width:100%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </table>
                <p style="background:greenyellow; display:block; width:100%; overflow:hidden; padding:10px 0;">
                <input class="myimage" style="margin-right:10px; padding:0 10px; float:right;" type="submit" value="Register"/></p>
        </form>
```

And I want to show Login Failed at the bottom of the form. Can anybody help, please? Thank you very much.

---

---

**[UPDATE]**

I have used the codes explained by @Mour and the code works like charm. Hoewever, I forgot one thing if this login form is shown by click function with javascript, which mean that if the text of `login` is clicked then this login form will be shown. So what I want now is if the login is failed, i want to keep this login form is keep showing up without having to click the login text anymore.

```
        <li>
            <a href = "javascript:void(0)"
               onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                         document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!--Black Overlay-->        
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay" onLoad="initDynamicOptionLists()"></div>

    <!--Pop Up Div-->       
    <div id="light" class="white_content">

    <div id="loginbox">
        <span id="login-form">Login</span>
            <form method="post" action="config-login.php">
                <table width="345" align="center" style="background:honeydew; vertical-align:top; margin:0px auto; border:solid medium yellowgreen;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="myimage">Email :</td>
                        <td width="196" style="padding-right:2px;"><input type="text" name="member_email" style="width:100%"/></td></tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="myimage">Password : </td>
                        <td style="padding-right:2px;"><input type="password" name="member_password" style="width:100%"/></td></tr>

                </table>

                    <div style="background:greenyellow; display:block; width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:10px 0; padding:10px 0;">

                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />

                        <p><?php 
                            if($_GET['result']=='failed'){
                            echo 'invalid login';
                            }?>
                        </p>

                        <input class="myimage" style="margin-right:10px; padding:0 10px; float:right;" type="submit" value="Login"/>

                        <span style="position: absolute; top: 11px; right:1px; color:white;" id="closeBlocked">
                            <a style="color:green; text-decoration:none; background:white; padding:10px;" 
                               href = "javascript:void(0)" 
                            onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
                                      document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><b>X</b></a></span>
                    </div>
            </form>

    </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End of Pop Up Div-->
```

Comment: You can use Ajax to achieve this.

Comment: set the error message in `session` and print it in view page.

Answer (score 1):

change config-login.php code as below

```
else 
 {
 header("location:.$return"."?result=failed");
 }
```

and in form write below code at top

```
<?php 
if($_GET['result']=='failed'){
echo 'invalid login';
}
```

Comment: I have voted up your answer. But I forget one thing you have to know. Please look at my update question if you can fix this too.

Answer (score 0):

with ajx u can achieve it very easily.
 else if u dont want to use ajax then when u redirect to login  page or error 
 do something  like below by sending some status type of variable with url
header("location : login.php?status='fails'");
 and on login page when user comes at login page check for this status variable if its ststus is fail u can alert some errors else u r good to go.

Comment: sure..   http://jqueryvalidation.org/    here u can try whatever u want firstly download and then play with  each and every example on ur local machine....

Answer (score 0):

You could also make an `array` or `object` and pass in the validation errors and then make it a `JSON` and pass it in the `header`.

I have written and used this, although it might not be the best, but its clean.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/argentum47/ecommerce/blob/master/Register.php) [link](https://github.com/argentum47/ecommerce/blob/master/signup.php) with relevant portions of the code.

```
switch($count){
    case 0:
           $array[$i++]='invalid or too short name. use alphanumerics,_';
           break;
    case 1:
           $array[$i++]='invalid or too short password,use alphanumerics,_,@ ,$';
           break;
    case 2:
            $array[$i++]="invalid email address";
            break;
    case 3:
            $array[$i++]="invalid or too short address, use alphanumerics,-,_,:";
            break;
    default:
            $array[$i++]="undefined error";
               break;
}
// ...
if($array!=NULL){
  $_SESSION['error']=json_encode($array);
  header('Location:./signup.php');
}

// Of course check for validation of JSON data. You will find it in the manual
if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
  print_r("<ul>");

  $array=json_decode($_SESSION['error']);
  foreach($array as $elem){
    print_r("<li>".$elem."</li>");
  }
  print_r("</ul>");

  unset($_SESSION['error']); 
  $_SESSION['error']=NULL;
}
```

Comment: I am a little puzzling with your codes above since I have not found any of my codes there. Would you apply yours with mine,please?